# What is the best way to find out why I'm getting a segmentation fault from traversing a linked list?

Tags: c, list

I am trying to find out and need help determining why my program gets a segmentation fault in my main:

```
int main (void){
  lista_conti *p = createlist();
  Conto c = malloc(sizeof(Conto));
  c->nome="uno";
  c->predecessore=NULL;
  c->costo=0;
  c->visited=0;
  insert(p,c);
  printf("\n%d\n", isEmpty(p));
  Conto con =p->conto;
  char *nome = con->nome;    /*SEGMENTATION FAULT*/
}
```

Here is the full listing of my program, including the main noted above.

/*My Struct*/

```
typedef struct lista_conti{

void* conto;
struct lista_conti *succ, *prec;
}lista_conti;


typedef struct{
  char *nome;
  lista_conti *predecessore;   /*valore hash(nome) del predecessore*/
  int costo;
  int visited; /*0 FALSE 1 TRUE*/
}*Conto;

lista_conti *createlist (void){

lista_conti *q = malloc(sizeof(lista_conti));

    if(!q) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Errore di allocazione nella creazione della lista\n");
        exit(-1);
    };
    q->succ = q->prec = q;
    return q;
}

/*Gli passo il puntatore alla testa della lista*/

int isEmpty(lista_conti *p){
  if(p == NULL)
    return 1;
  else
     return 0;
}
```

/*print full list*/

```
void printList(lista_conti *p){
    lista_conti *r;
     r=p;
     if(r==NULL)
    {
       printf("NO ELEMENT IN THE LIST :");
     return;
     }
   /* traverse the entire linked list */
    while(r!=NULL)
  {   
    Conto cnt = r->conto;     
    printf(" -> %s ",cnt->nome);
    r=r->succ;

  }
   printf("\n");
}
```

/* insert an element in head */

```
void insert(lista_conti *p, void* c){ 
   printf("nella funzione insert");
   if(isEmpty(p) == 1){
      printf("\nLISTA VUOTA\n");
      p->conto = c;
      p->succ=NULL;
   }

lista_conti *q = malloc(sizeof(lista_conti));
if(!q) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Errore nell'allocazione del nuovo elemento\n");
    exit(-1);   
};
q->conto = c;
q->succ = p->succ;
p->succ->prec = q;
p->succ = q;
q->prec = p;
}
```

/*  Insert an element in tail.
*/

```
void insertatend(lista_conti *p, Conto c){

lista_conti *q = malloc(sizeof(lista_conti));

if(!q) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Errore nell'allocazione del nuovo elemento\n");
    exit(-1);   
};
q->conto = c;
q->prec = p->prec;
p->prec->succ = q;
p->prec = q;
q->succ = p;
}




int main (void){
  lista_conti *p = createlist();
  Conto c = malloc(sizeof(Conto));
  c->nome="uno";
  c->predecessore=NULL;
  c->costo=0;
  c->visited=0;
  insert(p,c);
  printf("\n%d\n", isEmpty(p));
  Conto con =p->conto;
  char *nome = con->nome;    /*SEGMENTATION FAULT*/
}
```

after insert, when i try to access to con->nome, program return me Segmentation Fault. I don't know why. Is There a problem when i create list? when i insert?

Comment: have you tried running it with a debugger?

Comment: wroniasty is right. When you get a crash, any crash including segmentation fault, you should _always_ run the program in a debugger. It will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you see the cause of the crash.

Comment: Also, you can use the debugger to step through the code, one line at a time, to see that it does what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Upon initialization of your list, you create the first node with an uninitialized `conto` field.

After inserting a new node, the original first node remains intact, so when you're trying to dereference `p->conto` it will cause a segmentation fault.

The right way of creating a doubly linked list is by having another struct that holds the head and tail (you could also add a count if you like); they're both initialized as NULL.

Inserting updates the head, appending updates the tail.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a debugger. Assuming you are on a platform with GDB and GCC you would want to do the following to find where the segfault is occurring:

1- Compile you code with -ggdb. So you comple compile command might be gcc -ggdb list.c -o list  
2- Then run gdb list  
3- In gdb enter the following commands:

- run
- when you hit your segfault you should be able to use the GDB `list` command to view your source code
- And then to view the path your code took to arrive at the segfault you can use the backtrace command.

Please see this link showing [how to use GDB](http://yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html)

`

Comment: GDB is great, especially when coupled with things like Qt Creator.